# Store boost::timer results in a variable

Tags: c++, boost

I'm writing some some sort and search algorithms and testing them for a college assignment, I have to get the amount of CPU time and wall time used in processing the different tests. As well as individual timings.

I'm using the boost API to achieve this, my issue is that I have to run multiple test and get the average times, but I can't find a solution for storing the results boost gives in me in a variable.

Here is one of my algorithms:

```
int CA1::binarySearch(vector<int> v, int target)
{

    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t("%w");

    int top, bottom, middle;
    top = vecSize - 1;
    bottom = 0;

    while (bottom <= top)
    {
        middle = (top + bottom) / 2;
        if (v[middle] == target)
            return  middle;
        else if (v[middle] > target)
            top = middle - 1;
        else
            bottom = middle + 1;
    }
        return -1;
}
```

**Edit**

@Surt I'v tried to implement your code as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    cout << " enter the size of your vector\n";
    cin >> size;
    CA1 ca1(size);
    ca1.DoTests;

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}

int CA1::binarySearch(vector<int> v, int target)
{

    int top, bottom, middle;
    top = vecSize - 1;
    bottom = 0;

    while (bottom <= top)
    {
        middle = (top + bottom) / 2;
        if (v[middle] == target)
            return  middle;
        else if (v[middle] > target)
            top = middle - 1;
        else
            bottom = middle + 1;
    }
        return -1;
}

double measure(std::function<void()> function) {
    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    function();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>
        (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start_time);
    //std::cout << test << " " << static_cast<double>(duration.count()) * 0.000001 <<
    //           " ms" << std::endl;
    return static_cast<double>(duration.count()) * 0.000001;
}

void CA1::DoTests() {
    double time = measure(CA1::binarySearch(vectorUnordered,2));

    cout << time << endl;
}
```

But I'm getting errors thrown,

```
error C3867: 'CA1::DoTests': function call missing argument list; use '&CA1::DoTests' to create a pointer to member

functional(228) : see reference to function template instantiation '_Ret std::_Callable_obj<int,false>::_ApplyX<_Rx,>(void)' being compiled
```

any idea where I've gone wrong?

**Edit 2**

@Rob Kennedy

I've tried to implement your code std::bind but I cant get my head around it,
I've changed my code as follows:

```
double CA1::measure(std::function<void()> function) {
    auto startCpu = boost::chrono::process_real_cpu_clock::now();
    auto startWall = boost::chrono::process_system_cpu_clock::now();

    function();

    auto durationCpu = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>
        (boost::chrono::process_real_cpu_clock::now() - startCpu);
    auto durationWall = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>
        (boost::chrono::process_system_cpu_clock::now() - startWall);


    double cpuTime = static_cast<double>(durationCpu.count()) * 0.000001;
    double wallTime = static_cast<double>(durationWall.count()) * 0.000001;

    /*return static_cast<double>(duration.count()) * 0.000001;*/

    cout << "Cpu time " << cpuTime << endl;
    cout << "Wall time " << wallTime << endl;

    return cpuTime;
}


void CA1::DoTests() {

    auto time = measure(std::bind(binarySearch, vectorUnordered, 2));
}
```

Error thrown:

```
error C3867: 'CA1::binarySearch': function call missing argument list; use '&CA1::binarySearch' to create a pointer to member
```

Am I putting the std::bind in the right place? do I need to change the parameters in the measure()?
What exactly is it doing?

Comment: The error messages you're seeing have absolutely nothing to do with the timer. You're not passing a *function* to your `measure` function; you're passing an `int` — the one that's returned when you *call* `binarySearch`.

Comment: @johntk, `ca1.DoTests;` should be `ca1.DoTests`();

Comment: @Rob Kennedy I see that now, is there any way to pass a function like this that has a return value?

Comment: Hi @Johntk, in your main the `Dotest` should be a function call `Dotest()`

Comment: Thanks Surt, I was half asleep last night I don't know how I didn't notice that one, I fixed that and it has removed the first error, but I'm still getting the second error.

Comment: I have 4 function, 2 that take parameters and 2 that don't, neither type works. the function with parameters wont work because they are passing a value. The error I'm getting passing the function without parameters is: no suitable constructor exists to convert from void to std::function<void>

Comment: Yes. You want to use either `std::bind` (`measure(std::bind(binarySearch, vectorUnordered, 2))`) or a lambda function `measure([] { binarySearch(vectorUnordered, 2); })`).

Comment: @Rob Kennedy,  Where should I implement the std::bind?

Comment: You don't have to implement it. It's part of the C++ standard library already as of C++11, which we know you're using because you're already using `std::function`, another C++11 feature.

Comment: I edited my code with the error I'm getting, any idea where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using `boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer` but should use `boost::timer::cpu_timer` gory details [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html)

To ease the measuring use something like this, just exchange your favourite timer function with the std::chrono details:

```
double measure(std::function<void()> function) {
    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    function();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>
                   (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start_time);

    return static_cast<double>(duration.count()) * 0.000001;
}

void Test1() {
  ... setup test
  ... call test
  ... validate return
}

void DoTests() { 
  double time = measure(Test1);
  ...
  ... profit!
}
```

Comment: Ok so I think I understand your code correct me of I@m wrong,

So you've created a method called measure that returns a double and takes in as an argument a string and a function,
Then you start the timer,
call the passed in function,
get the running time, cast as a double and return the result.

Assuming That's right, correct me if it;s wrong, why are you passing the string in?

I have tried your code replacing

void CA1::DoTests() {
 double time = measure("Test1", CA1::binarySearch(vectorUnordered,2));
 
 cout << time << endl;
}

Comment: @johntk, measure returns the time used in MS, but your system timer might not be that accurate, see the link at the top. The idea is that you don't pollute the function you want measure with instrumentation and can reuse the timing code.

Comment: The string is not needed here, you can remove that code.

Comment: @johntk, I've removed the string in the code to not confuse.

Comment: I edited the question a bit, can you see the issue/s with my code?

I've removed the string in my code reflecting your edit.

Comment: I've changed the code some what and have it working for the wall time, now how do I get the CPU time using Boost?

Comment: You just replace the two `now()` with your `boost::timer::cpu_timer` finding the correct cpu_timer call in the link at the top. I don't have any experience with cpu_timer so you got to read the manual in the link.